# Colours for new accounts are the wrong way round in /tools

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

The newer account should be redder than the older account!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is a placeholder answer that calls attention to the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag in hopes that this answer gets accepted or up-voted so that Community♦ (that wily rascal) doesn't keep bumping this back to the front page every few weeks until the Eschaton.*

Comment: I guess you can call me the blue bomber, then, because my upvote will defuse that wily (heh) rascal.